# Once the program is opened through the terminal, is it possible to close it via a command in the same terminal window?

Tags: gnome-terminal

Is there a way to run commands in the existing terminal window with an opened app?
See for example the following screenshot:

[image]

Comment: It is not quite clear what you awnt, so I gave a few hints. Question title and body are quite different.

Comment: Do we have an XY problem here? What exactly is your issue and what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Think he might be asking for programs like 'top' that don't give an easy visible way to stop them, unless you know to use the 'q' key.  The terminal that top is running in, won't give a person the option to run another command till top is stopped.

Answer (score 0):

You can abort a running program by Ctrl+C.

If you run a command with `&` at the end like `libreoffice&`, you'll be able to run other commands in the same terminal.

You can also press Ctrl+Z to pause the running app and send it to background by `bg`.

Comment: `@`??? You mean `&`!

Comment: OOps...........

Comment: Pilot6, thank you very much for your detailed and very helpful answer!!! I'm a beginner and still learning the ropes!!! Thank you! (sorry that I can't upvote your answer due to low reputation)